# Getting com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown;

Tags: rabbitmq, channel

com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown; 
reason: Attempt to use closed channel

```
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQ
```

Channel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:190)

```
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:291)

at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:562)

at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:545)

at citylink.SearchNotification.completeTask1(SearchNotification.java:135)

at citylink.SearchNotification.run(SearchNotification.java:80)

at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)

at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, Actually I was keeping my channel open for long time. So RabbitMQ was closing the channel is it is no longer in use. So after using it I'm closing the channel and connection as well. Here is the code:

```
 try {
        //Create the Connection
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
        //Create the Channel
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();                    
        QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume(QueueName, consumer);            
        boolean removeAllUpTo = true;
        while(true){
            Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(5000);            
            if(delivery == null) break;
            if(processMessage(delivery)){
                long deliveryTag=delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag();
                channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, removeAllUpTo);
            }
        }          
        channel.close();
        connection.close(           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ShutdownSignalException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ConsumerCancelledException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```